# heroku integration workbook issue

Tags: integration, heroku

i was doing the [integration workboook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/integration_workbook/integration_workbook.pdf), but on Tutorial #3: Update the Heroku App
Step #2: Update your Application with a New Branch item #5: i am getting an error.

> In a browser tab or window, navigate to https://{appname}.herokuapp.com to see the changes (refresh your browser
>   if needed).

[image]

i followed all the steps and got no errors all the way until this one.

thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering if the configuration command in item #3 to set the access keys was processed correctly? Can you try the command "heroku config" (without the quotes) from the command line and check you see OAUTH_CLIENT_KEY and OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET parameters with the correct values?

Comment: @AndrewFawcett, the OAUTH_CLIENT_KEY and OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET are correct as per the connected apps consumer key